# How can I get this COUNTIFS formula to work?

Tags: excel, date, countif

I'm trying to tally up all the dates in the last 7 days. To do it, I've put together this formula

[image]

You can see that it's returning zero. However, here is the sample data that I'm working with...

[image]

It's formatted as date, too. Any idea why this COUNTIFS is returning 0?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put `TODAY()` function outside double quote. Try-

```
=COUNTIFS('Database Template'!$L:$L,"<=" & TODAY(),'Database Template'!$L:$L,">=" & TODAY()-7)
```